# Decimal number calculations in python

Tags: python, precision

I am new to Python. I have two simple questions. In my code, I need to do something like the following:

```
50-49.9==0.1
```

but python is giving `False`.  How can I correct this? Also, a similar wrong result I am getting is in the following:

```
int(10*(1-0.9))
```

I want the answer to be 1 but I am getting 0.

Comment: Maybe reading through this documentation will be helpful https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int

Comment: What did you expect from the first equation? The second must be due to rounding errors.

Comment: all floating point truncates towards zero. So `(1-0.9)` results in `0` so `int(10*0)` will result in `0`

Comment: In this case you are checking if `50-49.9 == 0.1`. The result is not always 0.1 unless you give `round(x,1)` so it rounds to 1 decimal place

Comment: OK, thank you. @JoeFerndz your comment was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In summary, the answer to your questions.

1. `50 - 49.9 == 0.1` will not equate to True as the left hand side is not rounded to one decimal place.
2. `int(10*(1-0.9))` will result in `int(10*0)` as the equation inside an int statement always truncates towards zero. More details are in https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int

Comment: Number 2 is not quite correct. The problem is that 1-0.9 evaluates to 0.09999999999999998. Multiply by 10, and the value is below 1. Converting to int will remove the fraction, giving 0

Comment: ... if you multiply with 100, instead of 10, it will give 9, not 0.